# Pure JS - Disable button in Onsen 2.0 / Monaca

Tags: javascript, onsen-ui, monaca

Using Onsen 2.0 with Monaca, I am having an issue setting the disable property to true via JavaScript and not Angular.  I am aware of how to do this with AngularJS and binding to a variable, but I just need to set the property via straight JS as this project is not using AngularJS at all.  I fear this may not be possible.

Here is the code which does not work:

```
<ons-button id="btn">Stop</ons-button>
<ons-button onclick="document.getElementById('myBtn').disabled = true;">Go</ons-button>
```

Edit:  Huge thank you to Fran again for solving my issue.  For others, since this is simply setting the CSS, to disable the button:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").setAttribute('disabled', '');
```

and to re-enable it after using setAttribute:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").removeAttribute('disabled', '');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`disabled` is not an internal variable, it's just an attribute used to apply some CSS. Try with `document.getElementById('myBtn').setAttribute('disabled', '')`.

Comment: Thank you.  Coming from a different language background has been confusing at times.  Especially, in regards to the help docs, such as: https://onsen.io/2/reference/ons-button.html.  Disabled is listed as an attribute with modifier, so I think of them as internal variables when in reality the attribute would be more like CSS classes (at least for button).    It becomes even more confusing in the docs, with a declared method of setDisabled(): https://onsen.io/2/reference/ons-button.html#method-setDisabled

Comment: @Munsterlander `disabled` is in the category "Attributes" in that link, so you can use `setAttribute`. It's true that there was a method `setDisabled` that internally just called `setAttribute`, but I think it's now removed from the beta. We still need to update the docs though.

Comment: Well that would make sense then @Fran-dios, ha!  I never thought about it like that, Attributes = setAttribute.  This will make a huge difference going forward.  Thanks again, like always!